# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Youmax youtube player muse

Tags: youtube

I design websites with adobe muse. So I don't know mutch about code.

I get this error with my youmax youtube player.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Between this 2 lines of code.

```
$('#youmax').append('<div id="youmax-tabs"><span id="youmax-featured" class="youmax-tab">Featured</span><span id="youmax-uploads" class="youmax-tab">Uploads</span><span id="youmax-playlists" class="youmax-tab">Playlists</span></div>');

    $(#youmax).append(<div id=youmax-encloser><iframe id=youmax-video width=+(youmaxWidgetwidth-2)+ height=+(youmaxWidgetwidth/youtubeVideoAspectRatio)+ src=frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe><div id=youmax-video-list-div></div></div>);
```

I have found similar problems with this error. And know there is probably a character that isn't allowed in this code. But I lack the knowledge To find that character.

Hopefully someone here can help me :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your reaction. I pasted the code into JSFiddle. This is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/ax09cesk/

Comment: I have added a working demo for your channel. If it solves your problem, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Youmax 5.0](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/02/youmax-50-complete-solution-for.html) works without any modifications on Adobe Muse.

I think you are using the version 2.0. In that case

You are missing quotes in the second line -

```
$('#youmax').append('<div id="youmax-encloser"><iframe id="youmax-video" width="'+(youmaxWidgetWidth-2)+'" height="'+(youmaxWidgetWidth/youtubeVideoAspectRatio)+'" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div id="youmax-video-list-div"></div></div>');
```

This should fix the error :)

**Edit 1 -----------------------------------------------------------------**

So this is your problem -

Insert your Youmax variables before you add the Youmax script. Also add you channel URL in the form - https://www.youtube.com/user/UCTc5sBk9CsWjXGHjNr0EYQA

```
youTubeChannelURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/UCTc5sBk9CsWjXGHjNr0EYQA';
youTubePlaylistURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrX';
youmaxDefaultTab = 'uploads';
youmaxColumns = 3;
youmaxWidgetWidth = ('897' == '100%' ? 640 : parseInt('897'));
youmaxWidgetHeight = 500;
var showFeaturedVideoOnLoad = false;
showVideoInLightbox = true;
```

After this call the script like -

```
<script src="./youmax.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an updated fiddle displaying your Channel with Youmax 2 - 
https://jsfiddle.net/ax09cesk/5/

Also here is a live edit demo for Youmax 2 -
http://demos.codehandling.com/youmax2/youmax.html

You can enter your channel URL as https://www.youtube.com/user/UCTc5sBk9CsWjXGHjNr0EYQA and watch your channel getting loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I did't figure it ouw in the code, It kept placing the video's all over the screen. Eventually I had to change the code to UNICODE. This way it did't change the original code

Comment: Umm.. not sure what code are you changing to UNICODE, but the code in my fiddle works just fine :)